# .loc with strip() and map()

Tags: python, dictionary, strip, pandas-loc

I everyone, I've gotten the dreaded "A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame." error.

I saw a possible solution here
[How to deal with SettingWithCopyWarning in Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20625582/how-to-deal-with-settingwithcopywarning-in-pandas) but it doesn't work with my example, since I'm trying to also use strip().

In a df with several columns, the type of "column_X" is object. I plan on later changing the strings to floats or integers. Currently, some values have a period followed by one or two zeros. So I want to strip everything starting from the period.

| column_x | column_y |
| --- | --- |
| "1.00" | 35 |
| "15.0" | 456 |
| "2.00" | 32 |
| "35.00" | 789 |

Here's my code:

```py
df['column_x'] = df['column_x'].map(lambda x: x.strip('.'))
```

Desired output:

| column_x | column_y |
| --- | --- |
| "1" | 35 |
| "15" | 456 |
| "2" | 32 |
| "35" | 789 |

Actual output:

> "A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
> Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead"

I'm not sure how to use .loc because most examples seem to have conditions
while my code uses .strip() while mapping.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please provide the expected [MRE - Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).
Show where the intermediate results deviate from the ones you expect.  We should be able to paste a single block of your code into file, run it, and reproduce your problem.  This also lets us test any suggestions in your context.
[Include your minimal data frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52413246/how-to-provide-a-reproducible-copy-of-your-dataframe-with-to-clipboard) as part of the example.

Comment: Hi Prune, I will try to follow MRE. Do that right now. Thank you for your comment.